# Azure Resource Template for new api app resource

Tags: templates, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-apps

I want to create an Azure Resource Group template which includes the new api app resource. I say new since api apps have changed: [App Service API Apps - What's changed](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/)
.

I tried this [Create a Logic App plus API app using a template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-arm-with-api-app-provision/) . Note: I don't want to create a logic app but this example also includes an api app. When I run this example I get a message: *There is a new version of API Apps. Click here to learn more*. So this is not the correct example. I can't find a better example.

Note:  when I simply add **"kind: apiapp"** to the "Microsoft.Web/sites" resource, no apiapp is deployed, I also don't get an error.

So my question is how to create a new api with Azure Resource Templates.

Comment: Have you tried this API App template from the Quickstart Github repo?  https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-api-app-gateway-new

Comment: Ok tried this and I have the same issue with this as mentioned above, I don't get the new api app. It says: API App - PREVIEW. And  "There is a new version of API Apps." If I create an api app by hand I don't see a warning or a preview postfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted MS for this, they helped me and now it's fixed. Their answer: 
*Have you installed the new Azure SDK version 2.8.2.1? In that release (actually in 2.8.1 and beyond) we added “Export ARM Template” capability to the provisioning UI. So when you go to publish, then click the New button, you can export your ARM template. That way you’d be able to see exactly the right syntax for creating an API App.*

So in VS create a web application, publish it to app service, check api app and then click the export button and you get the correct json.

See also:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/7163577-ability-to-export-a-resource-group-as-a-template